# Second setInterval function call conflicts with the first one

Tags: javascript, html

Hi and sorry for the long post,

I have this function that gets called when an HTML element is clicked.

```
function workItemClicked(imageID, clickedElement, toStart) {

    toggleShowcase(clickedElement, !toStart, imageID);
}

function toggleShowcase(clickedElement, enable, image_id) {

if (enable) {

    switch (image_id) {

        case 1:

            displayNextImage(clickedElement, br_images, true);
            br_interval = setInterval(function () {
                displayNextImage(clickedElement, br_images, false);
            }, 4500);
            break;
    }

} else {

    switch (image_id) {

        case 1:
            clearInterval(br_interval);
            break;
    }
    $(clickedElement).parent().removeClass("band-work-bg");
}


}
```

And when I click another element, it goes through the same method, with completely new parameters and it gets stored in another variable as well, to later stop it.
But if there are 2 of the "displayNextImage" functions running, the error happens.

This is my displayNextImage function:

```
async function displayNextImage(clickedElement, imgArray, firstTime) {

//Hide background
clickedElement[0].classList.remove("work-showcase-show");
clickedElement[0].classList.add("work-showcase-hide");
if (!firstTime) {
    await sleep(500);
}

x = (x === imgArray.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
//document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
clickedElement[0].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(" + imgArray[x] + ")";

//Show background
clickedElement[0].classList.remove("work-showcase-hide");
clickedElement[0].classList.add("work-showcase-show");


if (firstTime) {
    await sleep(1000);
    $(clickedElement).parent().addClass("band-work-bg");
}

}
```

It is an async function that loops through images for that HTML element, but for some reason if 2 or more displayNextImage functions are running, it gets stuck looping through the same image, and if the array has not enough images as the previous one, it crashes.

I think it comes from scope issues, I am not really familiar with javascript, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the line `x = (x === imgArray.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;` is x a global variable (because you set its value first time in this function but it depends on previous value, compared with imgArray.length - 1)? If yes (but it would be strange) check when and what value is set.

Comment: can you share the full code so i will help you :)

Comment: @kpower i think this actually might be it! Can you post this as an answer in case this is the issue? Setting the value as function parameter would solve this? (When I come from work, I will begin testing)

Comment: I can't fix the code because I don't know it in general. Your x value should be somehow calculated (for example, by getting index of clickedElement in array of possible elements to click or some other code to get it's order translated to image index). So it's not about passing it as function parameter (because this way you still need to calculate x outside and the problem is how you calculate it now).